# How to design partition key for a dimension table in ClickHouse?

Tags: partition, clickhouse

In my case, I need to load some dimension tables into ClickHouse to join with fact tables.

For example, a buyer (dimension) table to join with an order (fact) table:

```
select 
  order.id, 
  buyer.name
from order 
left join buyer
on order.buyer_id = buyer.id
```

In general, I shall create a `engine = Join` table. But some of my dimension tables are too large to fit in RAM, so I choose MergeTree engine as solution.
As we know, ClickHouse automatically cuts off the partition data where the partitioning key is specified in the query and use sparse indexes to locate data quickly.

My question is,

1. How to choose partition key for a MergeTree-engine dimension table?

   - Should I use hashed `id` as partition key, as a dimension table's
     `id` key is usually joined?
2. How many marks(parts) per partition is suggested?

   - As 8192 is a recommended granularity, I can set paritioning rules like modulo( id, 10) to control the number of partitions and the number of parts in partitions. 
     But how to set the ratio between the number of partitions and the number of parts in partitions to be more conducive to data compression and improve query speed?
     Does modulo( id, 10) way of partitioning damage data consistency and data compression?
3. Or, should I avoid creating dimension tables in ClickHouse and instead create a wide table that strictly meets the requirements?

Comment: Could you describe your requirements? I suspect you need to extract some analytics data (metrics) from raw data but not only do join tables.

Comment: About partitioning, if you need to calculate some metrics then make sense to use the wide table with *PARTITION BY toYYYYMM or toStartOfWeek or toYYYYMMDD (PurchaseDate)*. Other words, create chronologically partitioning as processing probably be chronological too.

Comment: 3. create a wide table.

CH Join does not do partition cutoff. You can do 'cutoff' in a join subselect 'all left join (select from dimension_table where date between)'. So your ideas about hashed id as partition key and modulo( id, 10) won't work and just make all worse.